# Power BI rounding in visuals

Tags: database, powerbi, grouping, rounding, visualization

Good afternoon,

Not sure if this is possible but I have a rather large data set that I have imported into Power BI. This is at local level and is unrounded.

When I pull through into the report, I group the data by region and then wish to round this grouped figure, rather than rounding first which I can do in the data sheet and then grouping as this knocks the total values out.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Andrew.

Comment: All the data is inside of a database?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana Yes - so the unsuppressed data is in a database that I have put into POWER BI. I need to round the data though before it is summed, which I can't seem to do in POWER BI. Can this be done or will I have to work on the SQL database feeding the POWER BI?

Comment: Hi then create a view in the database by rounding. And get the data from that view to Power BI. Or you can try direct query mode. When you are importing you can use a query built the sql query and execute that using Power BI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want - for rounding in Visualizations such as Card, you can modify the option in

Visualizations sidebar > Format your visual (paintbrush) > Callout value > Value decimal places